# blockdaemon SDK giving null in JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sdk, blockchain

I am trying to integrate blockdaemon in my project to track live transactions. I am passing auth key and my local server link but when I log SDK to check whether it is installed properly It returns null JSON. Please provide me step by solution to integrate and download blockdaemon in API

This is documentation I am referring to : https://docs.blockdaemon.com/reference/gettxsbyaddress

Code :

```
//sdk
const sdk = require('api')('@blockdaemon/v1.0#1y9nmvs34lm4whau1');
sdk.auth(api_key);
sdk.server(server_link);

//Routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).send(sdk);
});
```

Response :
{}

Error :

```
>                                          throw new Error("Sorry, `".concat(method, "` does not appear to be a valid operation on this API."));
>                                                ^
>
>  Error: Sorry, `toJSON` does not appear to be a valid operation on this API.
>      at Proxy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\chetan\OneDrive\Desktop\API\Blockdaemon\functions\node_modules\api\dist\index.js:179:47)
>      at step (C:\Users\chetan\OneDrive\Desktop\API\Blockdaemon\functions\node_modules\api\dist\index.js:33:23)
>      at Object.next (C:\Users\chetan\OneDrive\Desktop\API\Blockdaemon\functions\node_modules\api\dist\index.js:14:53)
>      at fulfilled (C:\Users\chetan\OneDrive\Desktop\API\Blockdaemon\functions\node_modules\api\dist\index.js:5:58)
>      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I want detailed explanation of getting all transaction from blockdaemon, download SDK and why JSON is returning NULL